# Why do my breakpoints duplicate in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging

I recently started having problems with breakpoints in Visual Studio 2010. When I set a breakpoint and then start debugging, another breakpoint appears on some other line nearby. The screenshots below shows the editor after I set a breakpoint, as well as the breakpoints window:

[image: Editor]

[image: Breakpoints window]

As soon as I start debugging, the breakpoint duplicates, as seen in the following screenshots:

[image: Editor while debugging]

[image: Breakpoints window while debugging]

**Why is this happening and how can I stop it?**

Comment: As a fall back, if no better answer comes your way, you could reset your settings.  See here: "Reset Settings - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273(v=vs.100).aspx"

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there is a child breakpoint set up, as described in the following MSDN articles:
<del>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b98cwcyw.aspx</del> (Link dead, see
[Child breakpoints VS 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b98cwcyw(v=vs.100).aspx))

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/02ckd1z7%28VS.71%29.aspx#vctskbreakpointswindowchildbreakpoints

Here is a similar question on StackOverflow, for which one of the answers contains a macro to remove child breakpoints.  Perhaps that might work for you?
[Disable/remove child Breakpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993568/disable-remove-child-breakpoints)

Alternatively, deleting the parent breakpoint (which will also remove the children) and re-creating it might help to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is because of mismatched newline endings. I had similar issue - multiple lines were marked as breakpoint location (say, 10 lines). Later I found it was because of only `\n` or `\r` present, instead of `CRLF` sequence.

Use Save-As, select `Save With Encoding..` option under `Save` button in `SaveAs` dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in VS 2008 and I **resolved by getting rid of the duplicated `.dll`** files in the compiling / debugging folders.
Please refer to my full response here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50063517/3603386

Answer (score 0):

Do you use **F10** (step over) when debugging?

**F9** is the shortcut to add/remove a breakpoint, you may be inadvertently hitting that.